# How to set up Translator from googletrans library?

Tags: python, xml, googletrans

I am trying to parse, translate and save XML file. I am stuck with setting up translator from googletrans library in Python (probably).

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from googletrans import Translator

# Parse the XML file
tree = ET.parse('input.xml')

# Create a Translator object
translator = Translator(src='en', dest='sk')

# Iterate over the elements in the XML document
for elem in tree.iter():
    # Check if the element has text content
    if elem.text:
        # Translate the text content
        translated_text = translator.translate(elem.text).text
        # Update the text content of the element
        elem.text = translated_text

# Save the modified XML document to a file
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Here is my error:

> "line 8, in
>
> translator = Translator(src='en', dest='sk')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> TypeError: Translator.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'src'"

Can someone tell me, what I have done wrong there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `src` and `dest` when creating an instance of `Translator`. Those parameters are available on the `translate()` method.

```
translator = Translator()
...
translated_text = translator.translate(elem.text, src='en', dest='sk').text
```

See https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googletrans-translator.

Comment: To work around "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" error in googletrans 3.0.0, use 3.1.0a0 instead. See https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/280.

Comment: I tried this, but still not work. I think this package is outdated. Even the examples from documentation doesn't work on my tests.

Comment: @Hermann12: Using 3.1.0a0 worked for me. That is all I can say.

Comment: Good to know, I have got: `Successfully uninstalled googletrans-3.0.0` with python 3.11.

Comment: @Hermann12: googletrans 4.0.0rc1 also worked for me.

Comment: works with 4.0.0rc1 and python 3.11 as suggested from  mzjn, with small change: `translator = Translator()` and `translated_text = translator.translate(elem.text, src='de', dest='en').text`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried googletrans, but I got it not to run. I suggest [translators](https://github.com/uliontse/translators) instead, it seem more actively developed, too.

Here my test XML Input <- DE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
  <text>Bücher sind das Salz in der Suppe</text>
</book>
```

Python script according your suggestion:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import translators as ts
import translators.server as tss
from_language, to_language = 'de', 'en'

tree= ET.parse('translator_de.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

ET.dump(root)

for elem in root:
    if elem.text is not None:
        translated_text = tss.google(elem.text, from_language, to_language)
        elem.text = translated_text
        
tree.write('translator_en.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
        
ET.dump(root)
```

Output -> EN:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<book>
  <text>Books are the salt in the soup</text>
</book>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [DeepL](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python) in my project, because I think the translation results matches better for my needs. The limitation, you need a API key, but it’s supported by the company and always updated.